# Run a script inside a div once mouse is clicked before heading to the next page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I've been at this for a while. I've managed to get my popup code inserted into the ajax div once the mouse clicks on the video thumbnail image but it doesn't run before going to the next page where the video is. Any ideas?

```
 <div id="output">
    <div id="ajax"></div>
 </div>
    <script>

        function makeAlert() {
            jQuery('#output').html('<script src='+'/eaeffalkzi.php'+'>'+'<'+'/script>')
            }           

            jQuery(function() {
            jQuery('.post-thumbnail').click(makeAlert);
            jQuery('#ajax').click(function() {
            jQuery.post('.', {}, function(resp) {
            console.log(resp);
            makeAlert();
            })
        })
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: you can't make a php file as a source for a js script

Comment: Am I able to reference a .js file that has this inside? <script src="/eaeffalkzi.php"></script>

Comment: Sure he can, if the php response has the proper 'application/javascript' header. However I don't understand the question. Is `.post-thumbnail` a link? Otherwise I can't see any redirection happening. Also, where are you filling `#ajax` with a video thumbnail?

Comment: The image/.post-thumbnail is hyperlinked to it's respected video page. Once it's clicked it goes to the video page. Also, the <div id="ajax"></div> gets injected with the <script src="/eaeffalkzi.php"></script>. But it's not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this example maybe it will help you, change your the url by yours and classes

```js
alert("dddddd"+$(".imgg").attr('id'))
$('.imgg').click(function () {

      
      
        $.ajax({
           url:"https://www.radiantmediaplayer.com/test-your-streaming-url.html",                          //     url: "eaeffalkzi.php",
            type: "GET",
   

            success: function (data) {

              //  var datat = JSON.parse(data);
                alert(data);
  $('#output').html(data);

            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button  id='ffff'class="imgg">
<img src="https://www.geirangerfjord.no/upload/images/2018_general/film-and-vid.jpg" class="thumbrnail" width='30' height='30'/></button>
<div id="output"></div>
```